# Elements moving out of vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having a layout issue. I'm using Bootstrap for this project but not for the cards.

The project is available here:
http://marcmurray.net/jay_test/#

The elements in the grid layout are all sized to the same height, but are not lining up on the same baseline. The cards with 2 lines seem to align higher up than ones with 1, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out why.
Not sure if I can link to a codepen as the cards are generated dynamically, but the CSS relating to them is here:

```
.mix {
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1em;
}


 .item {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}


.item-bottom {
  background-color: #f8f6f5;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  -moz-transition: all .25s;
  -ms-transition: all .25s;
  -o-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
  background-color: #F8F6F5;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened your website, and opened developer tools and removed `dispaly: inline-block;` from the element and it lined up nicely.

These probably shouldn't be inline-blocks. They're clearly block-level elements.

So: make them:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

and they show up and sit properly.

Note: you have to remove the hard-coded styling of inline-block on the actual cards themselves or it will override what you're got.